# Show that for a Hilbert Space $H\neq \{0\}$ there exists a total orthonormal set.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, hilbert-spaces

I need to show:

> Show that for a Hilbert Space $H\neq \{0\}$ there exists a total orthonormal set.

Case 1:$\dim H<\infty $

Let $B=\{b_1,b_2,\dots ,b_n\}$ be  a  basis of $H$.Since $B$ is a basis so the set  $\{b_1,b_2,\dots ,b_n\}$ is linearly independent and hence by Gram-Schmidt process I can create an orthonormal set out of $B$ say $B_1$ such that $\text{span  B}=\text{span} B_1=H$

Since $\text{span}(B_1)=H\implies B_1$  is a total orthonormal set of $H$.

Case 2:$\dim H=\infty $.

Can I use the same technique here also like the finite case since Gram-Schmidt process is applicable in infinite dimensional case also.

The problem is it is given that for $\dim H=\infty $ we should break it into two cases like $H$ is separable and not-separable.

Will someone please tell me why is it needed and if it is so how to do it?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot use the same proof, because a Hamel basis of an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space is necessarily uncountable.

The best way to prove this is by applying Zorn's lemma to the partially ordered set of all orthonormal sets in $H$ to obtain a maximal orthonormal set, and show that this maximal orthonormal set is total.

Comment: Should I break into separable and non-separable

Comment: @BenStokes How would you handle each case?

Comment: No need I have got the proof;Thank you

Comment: I think you do not need Zorn's lemma in the separable case. You might start with a countable dense subset and apply Gram-Schmidt.